# Converting Tables to AutoResize Divs

Tags: html, css, html-table

Currently I am using tables to show 4 cameras in equal size blocks: top left / top right / bottom left / bottom right. I would like to switch to divs, with the possibility that things could be a little more automatic.

Here is what I have:

```
<table border="">
   <tr>
      <td>
      <object id="Player1" height="600" width="800" border="" classid="CLSID:745395C8-D0E1-4227-8586-624CA9A10A8D">
         <param name="AutoStart" value="1">
         <param name="UIMode" value="none">
         <param name="MediaType" value="mjpeg">
         <param name="NetworkTimeout" value="5000"><!-- use this param if you want to change the network timeout -->
         <param name="MediaUsername" value="root"><!-- this param only necessary if restricted access is enabled -->
         <param name="MediaPassword" value="admin"><!-- this param only necessary if restricted access is enabled -->
         <param name="MediaURL" value="http://10.77.130.65/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=800x600&fps=10"><!-- your media url goes here -->
      </object>
      </td>
      <td>
      <object id="Player2" height="600" width="800" border="" classid="CLSID:745395C8-D0E1-4227-8586-624CA9A10A8D">
         <param name="AutoStart" value="1">
         <param name="UIMode" value="none">
         <param name="MediaType" value="mjpeg">
         <param name="NetworkTimeout" value="5000"><!-- use this param if you want to change the network timeout -->
         <param name="MediaUsername" value="root"><!-- this param only necessary if restricted access is enabled -->
         <param name="MediaPassword" value="admin"><!-- this param only necessary if restricted access is enabled -->
         <param name="MediaURL" value="http://10.77.130.67/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=800x600&fps=10"><!-- your media url goes here -->
      </object>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
      <object id="Player3" height="600" width="800" border="" classid="CLSID:745395C8-D0E1-4227-8586-624CA9A10A8D">
         <param name="AutoStart" value="1">
         <param name="UIMode" value="none">
         <param name="MediaType" value="mjpeg">
         <param name="NetworkTimeout" value="5000"><!-- use this param if you want to change the network timeout -->
         <param name="MediaUsername" value="root"><!-- this param only necessary if restricted access is enabled -->
         <param name="MediaPassword" value="admin"><!-- this param only necessary if restricted access is enabled -->
         <param name="MediaURL" value="http://10.77.130.70/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=800x600&fps=10"><!-- your media url goes here -->
      </object>
      </td>
      <td>
      <object id="Player3" height="600" width="800" border="" classid="CLSID:745395C8-D0E1-4227-8586-624CA9A10A8D">
         <param name="AutoStart" value="1">
         <param name="UIMode" value="none">
         <param name="MediaType" value="mjpeg">
         <param name="NetworkTimeout" value="5000"><!-- use this param if you want to change the network timeout -->
         <param name="MediaUsername" value="root"><!-- this param only necessary if restricted access is enabled -->
         <param name="MediaPassword" value="admin"><!-- this param only necessary if restricted access is enabled -->
         <param name="MediaURL" value="http://10.77.130.12/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=800x600&fps=10"><!-- your media url goes here -->
      </object>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to switch to using div's. I've looked around at stacked div's and it seems like I could have a container that specifys the over all width. In this case it would probably be 1080 or 720 TV screens. Would it be possible to have the 4 divs max out in the amount of available space and either do it automatically or by specifying the width.

The question I had: would it be able to do the height and width in the object line automatically based on screen size or the container width? And it's also hard coded in the url.

EDIT: `http://10.77.130.12/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=800x600&fps=10` (the width / height is hardcoded there) and also on the object line. Keeping things hardcoded I feel sure that I could switch things to divs. But having them automatically resize based on window size and interact with the video object is what I wasn't sure about. If that was even possible.

Comment: What's hard-coded in the URL?

Comment: There are a number of ways to go about this. You'll need a wrapper div with a width, like you mentioned, and you'll need floated or inline-block child divs. You really need to try it yourself before asking for help. The question is too general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use % for width and height, calculate accordingly and it would fit in your layout/viewport...

Parent div(Table) will be of width: 100%